# Browser thinks web component is already defined

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I'm trying figure out if there's a way to register an Angular component as a web component and pass it into an iframe's `srcdoc` property.  I'm using `angular/elements` in a somewhat unorthodox way in an attempt to achieve this but am getting the following error in my console

> Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "demo-component-c" has already been used with this registry

The problem is this happens no matter what I change the element's name to. Here's what I'm doing in my code

```
export class ResponsiveWindow {

    @Input() Demonstration! : Type<Component>; //I pass in a regular Angular component from the parent

    constructor( private injector: Injector ){}

    iFrameOnLoad = ()=>{  //the function I pass into the iframe's onload attribute

        const item = createCustomElement(this.Demonstration, {injector: this.injector});
    
        return customElements.get('demo-compomnent-c') || customElements.define('demo-component-c', item);
    }
}
```

Then in my template I do this

```
<iframe
    #domFrame
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
    srcdoc="<demo-component-c></demo-component-c>"
    class="domFrame"
    [attr.onload]="iFrameOnLoad()"
></iframe>
```

When I look in the inspector I can see `<demo-component-c></demo-component-c>` in the iframe's `body` element but nothing shows up in the iframe on my screen. The only thing I could think of to try is changing the name of the component.  The component I'm currently passing in is just a blank component I generated in the CLI so there's no functionality or markup aside from the `myComponent works!` that comes out of the box when you generate it so there's nothing to show in terms of the code with that.  I'm really going out on a limb with this idea so I don't know if it's even supposed to work or not.  Does anybody have any suggestions?